# Time Dependent Joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables where I have start and end date for each for each on both tables and I need to join them so that the record is valid for dates on both the tables

```
Table 1
EmpId   StartDate   EndDate
1   1/2/2017    12/31/9999
1   8/10/2016   1/1/2017
1   10/11/2015  8/9/2016
1   2/10/2014   10/19/2015

Table2
JobId EMPID StartDate   EndDate
J1  1        1/2/2017   12/31/9999
J2  1        8/10/2016  1/1/2017
J3  1        2/10/2014  8/9/2016

 Result Set Should be something like this 
EmpId   StartDate   EndDate
1   1/2/2017    12/31/9999   J1
1   8/10/2016   1/1/2017     J2
1   10/11/2015  8/9/2016     J3  
1   2/10/2014   10/19/2015   J4
```

Thanks in advance
Sri

Comment: there is no **1   2/10/2014   10/19/2015   J4** in table2. where you get this information ?

Comment: Sorry that has to be J3

Answer (score 0):

you can test a query like this:

```
SELECT
    t1.*
    ,t2.JobId
FROM
    table1 t1
LEFT JOIN
    table2 t2
ON 
    t1.EmpId = t2.EmpId 
AND 
    t1.StartDate = t2.StartDate 
AND 
    t1.EndDate = t2.EndDate;
```

Comment: This will find no match to 3 and 4 record because date conditions then the output will be something like this                                                                                     
     1   1/2/2017    12/31/9999   J1
     1   8/10/2016   1/1/2017     J2
     1   10/11/2015  8/9/2016       
     1   2/10/2014   10/19/2015'

Comment: if you dont want to have row 3 and 4 change **LEFT JOIN** to **INNER JOIN**

Comment: This 2 records from T1 will never meet the condition on T2 .. I want all the records from T1                                                                                              
1   10/11/2015  8/9/2016
1   2/10/2014   10/19/2015